# Yii2 photo gallery Photo->Likes relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

So basically, I have a photo application and the relation between photos and likes is `hasMany()`. How can I make the relation to be ordered by `count(number_of_likes)` for each photo?

```
TABLE `Likes` (
  `id_lk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idusr_lk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idpht_lk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_lk`),
  KEY `idusr_lk` (`idusr_lk`),
  KEY `idpht_lk` (`idpht_lk`),
  CONSTRAINT `Likes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idusr_lk`) REFERENCES `users_usr` (`id_usr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Likes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idpht_lk`) REFERENCES `photos_pht` (`id_pht`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

the php code of the relations: 
Photo model

```
public function getLikes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Likes::className(), ['idpht_lk' => 'id_pht']);
}
```

Likes model

```
public function getPhoto()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Photo::className(), ['id_pht' => 'idpht_lk']);
}
```

I know that you can add an `orderBy` clause after the relations, but I just simply don't know if i am allowed to write an SQL query there and if I am, how am I supposed to write it?

Comment: you would need to manage that when building your query , you are basically looking to utilize the relation when you need to show the listing of the photos along with the likes? if i am not wrong

Comment: also please describe the actual scenario where you are trying to use it, in GridView or some where else as there are different approaches to this but you need to take care of few things specially when you are using the Search model with GridView and want to show some columns that are not actually a part of the table schema

Comment: So, when i go to let's say the index route of photos controller, i want to get all the photos that are available in the database, ordered by the number of likes for each. As desired, a Photo::find()->all(); should return this thing, but it just simply orders them by the primary key id asc. I will use the resulting array in a view, but not with grid/detail, but by parsing each element returned and rendering a html/css combination of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you require is that you don't have to build the query manually every time and still able to call the result set which has

- All photos along with the number of likes they have using the existing relation `getLikes()`.
- They should be ordered according to the number of likes they have.

Well what i suggest wont just use `Photo::find()->all()` to do the job but yes if you are ok with doing `Photo::find()->byLikes()->all()` then you can use the following approach

- Create `ActiveQuery` Class `PhotoQuery` for the `Photo` model.
- Override the `find()` method inside your `Photo` Model to use the newly generate/created `PhotoQuery` class.

You can use `Gii` to generate the default `PhotoQuery` class or you can create manually like the below one.

Adjust the namespaces accordingly.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

/**
 * This is the ActiveQuery class for [[Photo]].
 *
 * @see Photo
 */
class PhotoQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return Photo[]|array
     */
    public function all($db = null)
    {
        return parent::all($db);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return Photo|array|null
     */
    public function one($db = null)
    {
        return parent::one($db);
    }
}
```

Now what you need to do is to add a new method in the `PhotoQuery` with the name `byLikes()`

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function byLikes()
{
    return $this->alias('p')
        ->select(['p.*', new \yii\db\Expression('count(l.idpht_lk) as likeCount')])
        ->joinWith(['likes l'])
        ->groupBy('p.id_pht')
        ->orderBy('likeCount desc');
}
```

and then add the following method in your `Photo` model to use `PhotoQuery` class instance.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @return PhotoQuery the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    return new PhotoQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

Now you can call the query like `Photo::find()->byLikes()->all()` and it will return the results ordered by total number of likes along with the likes count, where at the same time you can still call `Photo::find()->all()` to get only the photo specific result set if you want to somewhere in the future.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your table `Likes` you have to add a field where you can store the number of likes for each photo, for example: `number_of_likes`. 
Then you can run a query like this to get the number of like for each photo on descending order:

```
SELECT idusr_lk, idpht_lk, number_of_likes
FROM photos_pht
INNER JOIN Likes
ON photos_pht.id_pht = Likes.idpht_lk
ORDER BY  Likes.number_of_likes DESC
```

Comment: Isn't that field going to break the rule of "no calculated fields in a database" ?  I mean i thought of that too, but it's kinda not the way i wanted to do it.

Comment: If you are going to create a new line in the table for each like of a photo, its going to take more time to return the number of likes instead of just selecting the photo_id and returning the field number_of_likes